# Recursive Function - Javascript - sum of array elements equal to n

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I am working my way through the javascript course on freecodecamp and im confused with the lesson on recursive functions.

I am having difficulty understanding the following code:

```
    function sum(arr, n) {
        
       if(n<=0) {
           return 0;
       } else {
           return sum(arr, n-1) + arr[n-1];
       }
        
    }

sum([10,20,30,40], 3);
```

The specific part im struggling with is this:

- arr[n-1];

would the return line not be returning sum([10,20,30,40], 3-1) + arr[3-1] resulting in 30+30 = 60?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Or even pointing me in the right direction to look into this further.

Thanks

Comment: That's what it does. What other behavior are you expecting?

Comment: I’m expecting it to calculate 10+20+30 but it looks to me as though it is calculating 30+30?

Comment: It's calculating `sum([10, 20, 30, 40], 2)+30`, and `sum([10, 20, 30, 40], 2)` is `sum([10, 20, 30, 40], 1)+20`, and `sum([10, 20, 30, 40], 1)` is `sum([10, 20, 30, 40], 0)+10`, and `sum([10, 20, 30, 40], 0)` is `0` (because `n <= 0`). So, now, you evaluate on the reverse order, it's `0+10` (=10), then `10+20` (=30), then `30+30` (=60)

Comment: @scottm95 it calculates `0`, `0 + 10`, `10 + 20`, and `30 + 30`

Comment: Now that I thought about it, maybe part of the confusion is because coincidentally, 10 + 20 + 30 is also equal to 30 + 30. So maybe, if you used something like [1, 20, 300, 4000] instead, it would've been clearer that it was 1 + 20 + 300 = 321.

Comment: Yeah i see where both of you are coming from now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the original code in a more intuitive way by putting `arr[n-1]` first. This way we can keep expanding each call to `sum()` to the right.

But first let's note down what `sum(arr, n)` call will return for each `n`

```
if n > 0 => arr[n-1] + sum(arr, n-1)
if n == 0 => 0

n == 3 => arr[2] + sum(arr, 2)
n == 2 => arr[1] + sum(arr, 1)
n == 1 => arr[0] + sum(arr, 0)
n == 0 => 0
```

Now we expand our steps:

```
sum(arr, 3)
== arr[2] + sum(arr, 2) // expand sum(arr,2) where n = 2
== arr[2] + arr[1] + sum(arr, 1)  // expand sum(arr,1)
== arr[2] + arr[1] + arr[0] + sum(arr,0) // expand sum(arr,0)
== arr[2] + arr[1] + arr[0] + 0
== 30 + 20 + 10 + 0
```

Comment: Anytime! Select it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Test with

```
function sum(arr, n) {
    console.log(`calling sum(arr, ${n})`);
    if(n<=0) {
        console.log(`returning 0`);
        return 0;
    } else {
        console.log(`calculating [sum(arr, ${n-1}) + ${arr[n-1]}]`);
        let s = sum(arr, n-1);;
        console.log(`returning [sum(arr, ${n-1}) + ${arr[n-1]}] = [${s} + ${arr[n-1]}]`);
        return s + arr[n-1];
    }
}

sum([10,20,30,40], 3);
```

The output will be:

> calling sum(arr, 3)
>
> calculating [sum(arr, 2) + 30]
>
> calling sum(arr, 2)
>
> calculating [sum(arr, 1) + 20]
>
> calling sum(arr, 1)
>
> calculating [sum(arr, 0) + 10]
>
> calling sum(arr, 0)
>
> returning 0
>
> returning [sum(arr, 0) + 10] = [0 + 10]
>
> returning [sum(arr, 1) + 20] = [10 + 20]
>
> returning [sum(arr, 2) + 30] = [30 + 30]

Two other classic examples of simple recursive functions are factorial and fibonacci, because those two formulas itself are recursive. Multiplication could also be computed recursively, if you think as a * b being a + (a + ...) where a is added b times.

If you're trying to code those functions, there's a hint to code this last example:

> 5 * 10 is equal to 5 + 5 * 9, which is equal to 5 + 5 + 5 * 8 and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, its starting to make more sense but I’ll definitely need some more practice!

Answer (score 0):

sum([10,20,30,40], 3-1) Will call sum function again, think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions usually operate with a value that is immediately accesible and another value that they obtain by calling themselves until a base case is reached.

In this example, that accesible parameter is one of the numbers of an array and the operation is just a simple addition. The base case will be reached when the function's parameters satisfy the *if* condition.

Think of the different iterations that happen here to understand how the final result is gotten:

1. First iteration, **sum([10,20,30,40], 3)**

The *if* condition is not fulfilled because 3 (n) is greater than 0, so the *else* branch's code is executed.

We have sum([10,20,30,40], 2) +  arr[2]. We don't know the result of the recursive call yet but we have the value of the number located in the third position of the array, that is 30 (arrays are usually considered to start from 0).

2. Second iteration, **sum([10,20,30,40], 2)**

Again, this is not the base case yet (if branch), so we have:

`sum([10,20,30,40], 2-1) + arr[2-1] ->`
`sum([10,20,30,40], 1) + arr[1] ->`
`sum([10,20,30,40], 1) + 20`

3. Third iteration, **sum([10,20,30,40], 1)**

At this point, we have 30 and 20 as "partial results". These numbers and the results of the remaining iterations will all be added up, because that's what the code in the *else* branch does, an addition.

`sum([10,20,30,40], 1-1) + arr[1-1] ->`
`sum([10,20,30,40], 0) + arr[0] ->`
`sum([10,20,30,40], 0) + 10`

Another partial result has been added: 10.

4. Forth and final iteration, **sum([10,20,30,40], 0)**

The base case is finally reached, the *if* branch's code is executed and the recursion stops right here because there isn't another call to the recursive function in this code. The result of sum([10,20,30,40], 0) is **0** because the code returns 0.

Now that we have reached the end of the recursion, we can retrace our steps.

• The result of the third iteration is sum([10,20,30,40], 0) + 10. We know this is **0** + 10 now, so **10**.

• The result of the second iteration is sum([10,20,30,40], 1) + 20 = **10** + 20 = **30**.

• And the result of the first call and the original call to the function is sum([10,20,30,40], 2) + 30 = **30** + 30 = 60.

Recursive functions are really tricky at first but once you understand this logic of partial results that are "accumulated" until the moment the base case is reached, they get easier. Just take your time.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, it’s starting to make a lot more sense to me now!